# Facebook Login As App, access token doesn't work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-access-token

I am trying to get events from a Facebook page via Ajax.

But there should be no login process for user. For this reason I am trying to implement "Login as an App" by following the the documentation on [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/).

I am getting the access token correctly by

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
   &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
   &grant_type=client_credentials
```

However when I try to query Facebook Graph API with this access token I am getting an empty result set.

This is an example request;

```
https://graph.facebook.com/FAN_PAGE/events?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

I know the result set should not be empty because the same request with Graph Explorer returns the correct values.

Even a request like  `https://graph.facebook.com/FAN_PAGE/events?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_GRAPH_EXPLORER` works correctly.

Any idea on whats going on? How can I get this to work correctly?

Comment: Compare the two tokens using the debug tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Debuuger shows only the application ID for the first token. And some additional information for other token. However on facebook documentation says any valid token is enough to query posts or events. However I'm still getting empty result set.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the reason was not about the access token. The reason is that the page I want to get the events for is restricted. This works fine for unrestricted pages.

After a little research I found out that to read a restricted page's events (or posts etc.) you need a user access token. You get this by asking the user. (at login flow)

The other solution to get this data without prompting for a login is to get "page access token". You can generate a page access token by following [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-page/) link.

And more on [Access Tokens](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/)